# SDL_GetKeyName but for mouse and joystick input

Tags: c, input, mouse, sdl-2, joystick

I want to make a game where any action can be bound to any input, be it from a keyboard, mouse, controller. Think of scrollwheel bound to jump.

To do this I must be able to present the current bindings in a human readable fashion to the user in a UI, such as "Jump: spacebar" and "shoot: left mouse button".

Currently, in my input routine, I am converting a `SDL_KeyboardEvent` to a human readable string with `SDL_GetKeyName(event.key.keysym.sym)`.

I'm looking for a way to convert the following events into human readable text:

```
SDL_JoyAxisEvent
SDL_JoyBallEvent
SDL_JoyButtonEvent
SDL_JoyDeviceEvent
SDL_JoyHatEvent
SDL_MouseButtonEvent
SDL_MouseMotionEvent
SDL_MouseWheelEvent
```

I would expect the function to output something like "scrollup" or "X button" or "move up" or "left mouse button" or "select button". Currently I am manually implementing this, but it just seems so cumbersome. I've already looked at the docs but I couldn't find anything.

Sidenote: the documentation does not reveal whether a string from `SDL_GetKeyName` needs to be freed or not. I'm currently not freeing it.

My code currently:

```
SDL_WaitEvent(&event);

switch (event.type)
{
    case SDL_QUIT:
        quit = 1;
        break;

    case SDL_KEYDOWN:{
        const char* a = SDL_GetKeyName(event.key.keysym.sym);
        printf("Pressed down: %s\n", a);
        break;
    }

    case SDL_KEYUP:{
        const char* a = SDL_GetKeyName(event.key.keysym.sym);
        printf("Released: %s\n", a);
        break;
    }

    case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
    case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        switch (event.button.button)
        {
            case SDL_BUTTON_LEFT:{
                printf("LMB");
                break;
            }

            case SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT:{
                printf("RMB");
                break;
            }

            case SDL_BUTTON_MIDDLE:{
                printf("MMB");
                break;
            }

            case SDL_BUTTON_X1:{
                printf("X1");
                break;
            }

            case SDL_BUTTON_X2:{
                printf("X2");
                break;
            }
        }

        if (event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN){
            printf(" was clicked!\n");
        } else {
            printf(" was released!\n");
        }

        break;
    }

    case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:{
        printf("Mouse moved to (%d, %d)\n", event.motion.x, event.motion.y);
        break;
    }

    case SDL_MOUSEWHEEL:{
        printf("Scrolled ");

        if(event.wheel.y > 0){
            printf("up\n");
        }else if(event.wheel.y < 0){
            printf("down\n");
        }

        if(event.wheel.x > 0){
            printf("right\n");
        }else if(event.wheel.x < 0){
            printf("left\n");
        }

        break;
    }

    default:{
        printf("Unsupported input method\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the `test` directory in the SDL sources, there are a number of event/enum-to-string functions there that aren't present in the main API, if you're looking for something quick 'n dirty to copy-paste.

Comment: As you already did, names for mouse-related events can be easily hardcoded. I don't have experience with controller API, but there are `SDL_GameController...` functions (built on top of `Joystick`-functions, providing a higher-level abstraction), and they include `SDL_GameControllerGetStringFor...`.

Comment: @genpfault and HolyBackCat I can't upvote your comments for some reasons but thanks!